# PowerShell - Trying to use a variable in ScriptBlock with quoted string?

Tags: variables, powershell, scriptblock

I have the following PowerShell script Job that uses a ScriptBlock. I am trying to use the variable `$pw1` but it does not seem to be using it correctly. How can I use variables in a ScriptBlock or a string?

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\putty.exe" -argumentlist "-ssh Mark@192.168.1.3  -pw $pw1 -m C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\commands.txt -t" -passthru -Wait ;cmd.exe /c start cmd /k PSlist}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to fully understand your whole  `putty` call, but if you want to put your password argument (-pw) which in the `$pw1` variable of your calling script you should use the arguments :

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\putty.exe" -argumentlist "-ssh Mark@192.168.1.3  -pw $args[0] -m C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\commands.txt -t" -passthru -Wait ;cmd.exe /c start cmd /k PSlist} -ArgumentList $pw1
```

`$args[0]` will contain the value of `$pw1`.